# How to bind value from DataGrid:Cell to DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed-datagrid

My Problem:

- I have a Xceed `DataGrid` column with a button, which is bound to a Command (that part works)
- Now I want the button to be enabled/disabled depending on a certain value in the current `DataRow`.
- So far I can either get the command bind work or the `DataTrigger` depending on the `DataContext` I use, but not both at the same time.

I am stuck with the following code:

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="OpenInPiWebIdentifier"
             Title="PiWeb Report"
             VisiblePosition="6">
    <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(xcdg:DataGridControl.ParentDataGridControl).DataContext}"
                    Content="Open PiWeb"
                    Command="{Binding OpenPiWebCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.ResultData/PiWebReport, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PiWebReport}"
                                         Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled"
                                        Value="False" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
</xcdg:Column>
```

And the view model implementation of the command:

```
public ICommand OpenPiWebCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _OpenPiWebCommand;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != _OpenPiWebCommand)
        {
            _OpenPiWebCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OpenPiWebCommand");
        }
    }
}

private ICommand _OpenPiWebCommand;
```

In the constructor I initialize the command:

```
OpenPiWebCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(OpenPiWeb));
```

The property `PiWebReport` belongs to a class `ResultDataV1`. All data is put into this property `ResultData = new ObservableCollection<ResultDataV1>();` 
which is displayed in the `DataGrid` as columns/rows. 
So, now I can access either the property value `PiWebReport` or the command, depending on the context I use, but not both at the same time.

The data class:

```
public class ResultDataV1
{
    public ResultDataV1(long dataId, DateTime dateTime, DateTime? endDateTime, string partId, string scanId, bool measurementNotVolumejoin, string piWebReport, FileInfo volumeFileInfo, FileInfo volumeVglFileInfo, DirectoryInfo volumeDirectoryInfo, string inspectionPlanName, string paletteName, AutomationStateEnum? automationState);

    public AutomationStateEnum? AutomationState { get; }
    public long DataId { get; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; }
    public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; }
    public string InspectionPlanName { get; }
    public bool MeasurementNotVolumejoin { get; }
    public string PaletteName { get; }
    public string PartId { get; }
    public string PiWebReport { get; }
    public string ScanId { get; }
    public List<SubResultDataV1> SubResults { get; }
    public DirectoryInfo VolumeDirectoryInfo { get; }
    public FileInfo VolumeFileInfo { get; }
    public FileInfo VolumeVglFileInfo { get; }
}
```

Comment: "but not both at the same time." What would you like to achieve? "Both" at the same time?

Comment: Could you please post the implementation of the `ViewModel` which contains the definition of the `OpenPiWebCommand` property?

Comment: Updated post by adding the view model implementation.

Comment: Thanks! But there is an open question about "both" (please see the first comment).

Comment: Ok, sorry, did not read for first comment! With both I mean: The binding of the "OpenPiWebCommand" and the one of the DataTrigger.

Comment: The binding of the Command and also the CommandParameter works when using the DataContext I use in the example above. But the same value: "PiWebReport" from a cell does not work in the DataTrigger. It only works when using another DataContext: `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:Cell}},Path=DataContext}' , but then the command does not work anymore

Comment: Good. Could you please post the more or less **complete** implementation of the `ViewModel` (command initialization, `PiWebReport` property and its usages within the `ViewModel`)?

Comment: Further info attached. Hope this is sufficient

Comment: Sorry, but still do not have the "whole picture": not all the required code is posted to reproduce the behavior. Please see [the page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, I am sorry I couldn´t make the point! Instead of giving you more code and making it more complex, just a more abstract question: How would you enable/disable a button in a dataGrid row, depending on one of the field values of this row? I thought best would be to use a Button.Style, but is there another way by binding the IsEnabled attribute to something like CanExecute? Btw. I am using RealyCommand!

Comment: 1. `PiWebReport` seems to be a property of the same `ViewModel` as `OpenPiWebCommand`? 2. Could you please post the implementation of `PiWebReport` property?

Comment: It´s basically a simple string property of the data class ResultDataV1, which appears in the data grid. Above you´ll find the class.

Comment: The property is called "ResultData" of the type: ObservableCollection<ResultDataV1>), which belongs to the same ViewModel as the OpenPiWebCommand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is to use the [ICommand.CanExecute Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Initially the button becomes enabled or disabled based on the value of the method (of the bound `ICommand` instance). Also, firing [ICommand.CanExecuteChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to notify the user-interface (`Button` class) about the property change.

The implementation of the structure:

```
internal sealed class ResultData
{
    private readonly string piWebReport;

    public ResultData(string piWebReport)
    {
        this.piWebReport = piWebReport;
    }

    public string PiWebReport
    {
        get { return this.piWebReport; }
    }
}
```

The implementation of the `ViewModel` class:

```
internal sealed class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ResultData> items = new[]
        {
            new ResultData("Report 00"),
            new ResultData("Report 01"),
            new ResultData("Report 02"),
            new ResultData(null)
        };

    private readonly ICommand openPiWebCommand;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        openPiWebCommand = new RelayCommand<ResultData>(
            OpenPiWeb,
            x => x != null && x.PiWebReport != null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ResultData> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
    }

    public ICommand OpenPiWebCommand
    {
        get { return openPiWebCommand; }
    }

    private void OpenPiWeb(ResultData data)
    {
        // Implement the command logic.
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xcdg="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/datagrid"
        ...>
    <Grid>
        <xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
                <xcdg:Column FieldName="PiWebReport"
                             Title="PiWeb Report">
                    <xcdg:Column.DisplayMemberBindingInfo>
                        <xcdg:DataGridBindingInfo Path="." ReadOnly="True" />
                    </xcdg:Column.DisplayMemberBindingInfo>

                    <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Button Content="Open PiWeb"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(xcdg:DataGridControl.ParentDataGridControl).DataContext.OpenPiWebCommand}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                </xcdg:Column>
            </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        </xcdg:DataGridControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

References:

- Example of `Column.DisplayMemberBindingInfo` usage: [Difficult choice of grid for projects on WPF](http://sysmagazine.com/posts/167751/).

Hope this is useful for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints and the example! The CanExecute method is definitely the correct approach, but even when trying that, I got only all buttons of the column enabled/disabled and not just each cell. I figured eventually that I had to select the specific context: `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.PiWebReport, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:Cell}}}"
                Value="{x:Static System:String.Empty}">` And that works perfectly, but anyway I will now change it to the CanExecute method approach in order to make it the way it should.